# Managed Property mapped to Crawled property appears twice in Search Schema?

Tags: search, managed-property, search-schema

I added a managed metadata column to a document library (KBCategory).  The column was crawled because I can see it in my Search Schema.  Can anyone explain why there are two crawled properties (ows_KBCategory and ows_taxIdKBCategory)?  I would like to customize an item display template to surface this information.

Do I use the automatically mapped managed property below, or should I create a managed property and map the "Non taxId" property?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ows_KBCategory** = Text of the metadata field

**ows_taxId_KBCategory** = Unique ID of the metadata term

The ID property is used to get terms which are tagged or are a children of a term.  So in your case the regular ows_KBCategory should be sufficient.

For more information check to following link an scroll to the part **Data format for Managed Metadata**:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/automatically-created-managed-properties-in-sharepoint